# Rails can't find assets if not explicitly set asset paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a legacy application with disabled asset pipeline. I updated rails to 3.2.13, added `:assets` group in Gemfile, enabled assets in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

But assets won't load and compile before I explicitly set assets paths:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "stylesheets")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "javascripts")
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
```

I know that it **must** work without setting paths explicitly. But I just can't understand why it doesn't work now. It just works only when I define paths in my config files. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your `application.rb`? The interesting parts are : does it `require "sprockets/railtie"` and the `if defined?(Bundler)` routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in [active_reload](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload) gem, it was included in Gemfile long time ago, and it is deprecated for Rails 3.2+. Removal of this gem fixed assets.